# How to write a HQL query for Many To Many Associations?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have 3 tables, `Role[roleId, roleName]`, `Token[tokenID, tokenName]` & `ROLETOKENASSOCIATION[roleId, tokenID]`. The 3rd one was created automatically by hibernate. Now if i simply write a Query to get all the objects from Role class means, it gives the all role objects along with the associated tokenID & tokenName.

I just wanted the association as unidirectional. i.e: Roles--->Tokens
So the annotation in the Role class looks like,

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int roleId;
private String roleName;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="ROLE_TOKEN_ASSOCIATION",
 joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="roleId")},
 inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="tokenID")})
private List<Token> tkns;
    //Getters & Setters
```

Now i want the tokenNames for the specific roleId.
First i made a query like this `SELECT tkns.tokenName FROM Role WHERE Role.roleId=:roleId`
But, i ended up with some dereference error.

Then i changed the query to `SELECT tkns FROM Role r WHERE r.roleId=:roleId`
Now i have got what i wanted. But it comes with roleId too.

How shall i get tokenName itself?
Actually my problem is solved, but i would like to know how to do it.

*It ll be helpful to me, if anyone explains the Query Construction.*

Any suggestions!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried

```
SELECT t.tokenName FROM Role r JOIN r.tkns t WHERE r.roleId = :roleId
```

**EDIT:** This query almost directly maps to the corresponding SQL query where `Role r JOIN r.tkns t` is a shorthand syntax for the SQL join via the link table `Role r JOIN ROLETOKENASSOCIATION rt ON r.roleId = rt.roleId JOIN Token ON rt.tokenId = t.tokenId`. Affe's answer is another syntax for the same query.

**See also:**

- [Chapter 14. HQL: The Hibernate Query Language](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)

Comment: Actually, i am new to hibernate & HQL. It would be helpful to me if you explain the Query!!!

Answer (score 2):

You want a scalar list of just the name field?  You should be able to get that like this

```
select t.name from Roles r, IN(r.tkns) t where r.roleId = :id
```